# Convert a string to an array without splitting it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it somehow possible to convert a `string` to an `array` as easy as possible without any hacks? and **without splitting** the `string` at some point?

For example bringing this:

```
temp = 'Text';
```

to this:

```
temp = ['Text'];
```

It might be a simple question but I couldn't find any solution **without splitting** the `string`.

Comment: `temp = [temp];` ? It is not really clear what you are asking...

Comment: Weeell yeah that's the solution. Didn't thought about that, sorry.

Comment: Why not just create an array and add your string to it????

Comment: Do you want the string split? `[ "T", "e", "x", "t" ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an array with the string as a single value just create a new array with that string.

```
temp = [temp];
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const temp = 'text';

console.log(new Array(temp));
console.log([temp]);
console.log(temp.split());
console.log([].concat(temp));
```

There are a few options out there.